# Getting "ImportError: No module named" with parallel python and methods in a package

Tags: python, parallel-python, dill

I'm trying to use parallel python in order to do some distributed benchmarking (essentially, coordinate and run some code on a set of machines from a central server). The code I had was working perfectly fine until I moved the functionality to a separate package. From then on, I keep getting `ImportError: No module named some.module.pp_test`.

My question is actually two-fold: has anyone ever came across this problem with `pp`, and if yes, how to solve it? I tried using `dill` (`import dill`), but didn't help. Also, is there a good replacement for parallelpython, that doesn't require any additional infrastructure?

The exact error I get is:

```
RUNNING TEST
Waiting for hosts to finish booting....A fatal error has occured during the function execution
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ppworker.py", line 86, in run
    __args = pickle.loads(__sargs)
ImportError: No module named some.module.pp_test
Caught exception in the run phase 'NoneType' object is not iterable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    p.ping_pong()
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/pp-test/some/module/pp_test.py", line 5, in ping_pong
    a_test.run()
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/pp-test/some/module/pp_test.py", line 27, in run
    pong, hostname = ping()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

The code is structured this way:

```
pp-test/
       test.py
       some/
            __init__.py
            module/
                   __init__.py
                   pp_test.py
```

The `test.py` is implemented as:

```
from some.module.pp_test import MWE

p = MWE()
p.ping_pong()
```

While `pp_test.py` is:

```
class MWE():
  def ping_pong(self):
    print "RUNNING TEST "
    a_test = PPTester()
    a_test.run()

import pp
import time
from sys import stdout, exit

class PPTester(object):
  def run(self):
    try:
        ppservers = ('10.10.10.10', )
        time.sleep(5)
        job_server = pp.Server(0, ppservers=ppservers)
        stdout.write("Waiting for hosts to finish booting...")
        while len(job_server.get_active_nodes()) - 1 < len(ppservers):
            stdout.write(".")
            stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(1)

        ppmodules = ()
        pings = [(server, job_server.submit(self.run_pong, modules=ppmodules)) for server in ppservers]
        for server, ping in pings:
            pong, hostname = ping()
            print "Host ", hostname, " is alive!"

        print "All servers booted up, starting benchmarks..."
        job_server.print_stats()
    except Exception as e:
        print "Caught exception in the run phase", e
        raise
    pass

  def run_pong(self):
    import subprocess
    p = subprocess.Popen("hostname", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    (output, err) = p.communicate()
    p_status = p.wait()

    return "pong ", output
```

Comment: I ended up using dispy instead of parallel python...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dill` won't work with `pp` out of the box, because `pp` doesn't serialize the python objects -- `pp` extracts the object's source code (like the `inspect` module in the standard python library).

To enable `pp` to use `dill` (actually `dill.source`, which is `inspect` augmented by `dill`), you have to use a fork of `pp` called `ppft`. `ppft` installs as `pp` (i.e. imports with `import pp`), but it has much stronger source inspection, so you can automatically "serialize" most python objects and have `ppft` track down their dependencies automatically.

Get `ppft` here: https://github.com/uqfoundation

`ppft` is also `pip` installable and python `3.x` compatible.